# Ajax call returning json locally but xml when run on the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have an ajax call that returns some data. When I run the web page through visual studio and look at the result in developer tools I see `{"d":{"__type":"WebService+MyObject` etc... However when I run the same code through iis the ajax response looks like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyObject` etc...

I'm assuming I'm missing some setting, but I'm can't figure out what it might be.

Why am I getting json when running through visual studio but xml when running through iis.

Comment: It seems as though I fixed the problem with adding in some of the pieces of web.config I was missing based on this article: `http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/configuringaspnetajax.aspx` still not sure why it worked locally...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the content type of header from request.

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Server side method that respond to your Ajax call.

Comment: When I put that code in it doesn't know what Response is. What can I do qualify "Response". Also, I tried putting this `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` at the top of my web method, but I got the same result. Because this is happening only when running through IIS but not when running through visual studio I'm wondering if I need to change a setting in visual studio.

Comment: I tried putting the following in my web method `Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";` and that didn't work either.